# specify a timeout to the initial WSDL retrieval with JAX-WS?

Tags: java, wsdl, timeout, jax-ws

What is the best way to specify a timeout to the initial WSDL retrieval with JAX-WS?

It seems possible to specify timeouts for the Web Services calls using:

```
((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 2000);
((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, 2000);
```

but it doesn't affect the initial retrieval of the WSDL file.

It also seems possible to specify globally a timeout for all HttpUrlConnection calls using this system property:

```
sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout
```

but it affects all calls not just this one.

Also is there a simple way to use a local copy of the WSDL file so that this initial retrieval of the WSDL file is not performed?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming unmanaged clients:

If you're using generated bindings, there should be a constructor that takes a URL. This URL can point to a local resource (e.g. the classpath.) If you're using a dynamic client, use the [`Service.create(URL, QName)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/ws/Service.html#create%28java.net.URL,%20javax.xml.namespace.QName%29) method to do the same. See [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2011/04/java-jax-ws-web-services-and-clients.html) for examples.

In a managed client container, the service can be loaded using a bundled WSDL as specified in JSR 109.